# C# Check if image appears on screen

Tags: c#, image

I have a cropped version of an image that should appear on my screen.

`Image 6Island = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\6Island.png");`

Now the next goal is to Take an image of the screen.

```
Bitmap CaptureScreen()
    {
        var image = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        gfx.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        return image;
    }

Image 6Island = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\6Island.png");
Image currentView = CaptureScreen();
```

I then want to see if I can I can find the image `6Island` inside the new image. And the colors may vary a tiny bit. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Compare it pixel by pixel

Comment: @x... How do you suggest I do that?

Comment: explain what is meant by"6Island inside the new image", what is the logic you want to apply in terms of image processing techniques.

Comment: I want to see if a certain image appears on the screen. With a slight variation in color

Comment: In Bitmap there is a method GetPixel and return value is color. Just compare it first bitmap with second bitmap. Run it from top left to bottom right.

Comment: @x: the OP capture the screen with parameters which may be different than the original file -  var image = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb), so he can't compare pixel by pixel.

Comment: You may want to look into the field of **computer vision**. [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is a popular library.

Comment: Convert both images into monochrome or grayscale. Their comparison would be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

This is just sample quick and dirty and very slow, but it works. This code make a "crop" of your big bitmap and compare it with your small bitmap. If equal then percentage must be 100, if unequal then percentage lower than that. I would say, if bigger than 98%, then you found it.

```
private static void CompareBigAndSmallBitmaps(string fileName1, string fileName2)
{
  var bmpBig = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(fileName1);
  var bmpSmall = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(fileName2);
  for (var offX = 0; offX < bmpBig.Width - bmpSmall.Width; offX++)
  {
    for (var offY = 0; offY < bmpBig.Height - bmpSmall.Height; offY++)
    {
      var percentage = CompareSmallBitmaps(bmpBig, bmpSmall, offX, offY);
      if (percentage > 98.0)  // define percentage of equality
      {
        // Aha... found something here....and exit here if you want
      }
    }
  }
}

private static double CompareSmallBitmaps(Bitmap bmpBig, Bitmap bmpSmall, int offX, int offY)
{
  var equals = 0;
  for (var x = 0; x < bmpSmall.Width; x++)
  {
    for (var y = 0; y < bmpSmall.Height; y++)
    {
      var color1 = bmpBig.GetPixel(x + offX, y + offY).ToArgb();
      var color2 = bmpSmall.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb();
      if (color1 == color2)
      {
        equals++;
      }
    }
  }
  return (Convert.ToDouble(equals)/Convert.ToDouble(bmpSmall.Width*bmpSmall.Height))*100.0;
}
```

Comment: _if (color1 == color2)_ this will not work as the colors may vary a little as stated in the op. Either a color distance function with an epsilon is needed or maybe a simple truncation will also do: shift each channel to the right for 1-4 pixels and compare the truncated colors..